# Edit Distance Between Two Strings

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, edit-distance

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

inline size_t min(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    if (x < y)
        return x < z ? x : z;
    else
        return y < z ? y : z;
}

size_t edit_distance(const string& A, const string& B)
{
    size_t NA = A.size();
    size_t NB = B.size();

    vector<vector<size_t>> M(NA + 1, vector<size_t>(NB + 1));

    for (size_t a = 0; a <= NA; ++a)
        M[a][0] = a;

    for (size_t b = 0; b <= NB; ++b)
        M[0][b] = b;

    for (size_t a = 1; a <= NA; ++a)
        for (size_t b = 1; b <= NB; ++b)
        {
            size_t x = M[a-1][b] + 1;
            size_t y = M[a][b-1] + 1;
            size_t z = M[a-1][b-1] + (A[a-1] == B[b-1] ? 0 : 2);
            M[a][b] = min(x,y,z);
        }

    return M[A.size()][B.size()];
}

int main()
{
    assert(edit_distance("ISLANDER", "SLANDER") == 1);
    assert(edit_distance("MART", "KARMA") == 5);
    assert(edit_distance("KITTEN", "SITTING") == 5);
    assert(edit_distance("INTENTION", "EXECUTION") == 8);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

- Implementation:

  - It’s generally discouraged to open namespaces (`using namespace …;`). Instead, import single symbols (`using std::vector;`) or qualify symbols explicitly.
  - Three-ways min can be written entirely in terms of `std::min`:

    ```
    template <typename T>
    T min(T const& a, T const& b, T const& c) {
       return std::min(std::min(a, b), c);
    }
    ```
- “Bug”: the edit distance generally defines the cost for a substitution as 1 (since Levenshtein defined three equivalent edit operations), not 2 which you used in your code;
- Algorithmic: Your code needs O(*n* * *m*) space. There’s a not too hard to implement variant which requires just O(min{*n*, *m*}) due to the fact that for the computation we only need to save the previous column (or row). In fact, with a bit of trickery you can make do with a *single* vector and two additional variables to save all the active values.

But apart from that it’s a very clean and efficient implementation.

Comment: In practice `using namespace std;` is placed in a global header for most C++ projects and code is written to avoid name collisions with the standard library.

Comment: The replace cost was intentionally 2, as this is a different metric than Levenstein difference.  I have however changed it to parameterize it (insert_cost, delete_cost, replace_cost).

Comment: @user1131467 `using namespace std;` in a *header* is unacceptable. That’s effectively a bug, since this declaration **cannot be reversed** and this *will* lead to conflict with other libraries over which you have no control, because the effect is nonlocal. This practice precludes every use of 3rd party libraries, and requires very careful coding on your part to boot; I would also discourage avoiding name collisions with the standard library – this makes some obvious names unavailable (which leads to obtuse, non-obvious naming) and this is a problem that’s solved by namespaces.

Comment: Ok, so many of the multi-million line C++ codebases have this "bug", as does much of the C++ software you use everyday.

Comment: @user1131467 The fact that thousands of programmers look at examples of bad legacy code and copy what they see does not magically make it good practice. Konrad makes an excellent point here, but of course you're always free to do with it what you wish.

Comment: @DanielStandage: I think the reason it is so popular is not because of dogma, but because most people prefer not to have to write boilerplate code (`using namespace std;` in every file, or `std::` before every standard library symbol) just for some theoretical problem ( name collisions with standard library) that almost never comes up in practice.  On the very odd occasion it does there are workarounds (wrapping include in namespace or placing include before global `using namespace std;`, or patching the third-party library, etc).

Comment: @user1131467 You are wrong if you think this is not a problem in practice. It can cause very common name clashes, it’s definitely not “the very odd occasion”. And I don’t think it’s used in the headers of many modern C++ projects (but 80% of everything is crap according to Sturgeon’s law). And there’s a difference between qualifying names and boilerplate code as the latter would be avoidable with a better language design. But qualifying name happens in every well-designed language. Writing a single `using [namespace]` declaration at the beginning of a file cannot be too much to ask for.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Provide an example of a third-party library that has one of these "very common" naming conflicts with the standard library.

Comment: @user1131467 EASTL. Boost.MPL. Boost.Spirit. Heck, a lot of Boost libraries, which are lauded for their extremely high quality and are probably the most widely used C++ libraries.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Those aren't real conflicts - they are all defined within namespaces - so even if you open all the namespaces - ambiguity is only a problem when you try and use an unqualified name with two definitions visible from the translation unit (eg `ref` could mean `std::ref` or `phoronix::ref`).  You just qualify the name with the appropriate namespace to resolve the ambiguity when the compiler complains.

Comment: @user1131467 No, it's not only a problem when you do that. It's also a problem when you forget to `using namespace phoronix` and now you're inadvertedly using `std::ref` when you meant `phoronix::ref`, but the compiler doesn't help you in the slightest there. It's also a problem when ADL picks up the wrong things because you never intended for ADL to be doing anything here. Wrapping an `#include` in a namespace is also a bad idea that will probably lead to linker errors down the line.

Comment: @user1131467 Scratch that, I was wrong. But in addition to what Martinho said, consider every single C library without prefixes, they all become unusable by this. And you cannot fix this since wrapping the headers in a namespace would modify their symbol names (i.e. that would only work with header-only libraries).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The practice of importing using namespace std in almost every major C++ project means that if a C library cannot handle it, it won't get very far (this is what I was asking for an example of).  It just doesn't come up.  (Also I think you can use `extern "c"` in combination to link across the surrogate namespace.)

Comment: You chased him off :(

Answer (score 5):

I hope you're enjoying the NLP class. I do. :)

**Min**

```
inline size_t min(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    if (x < y)
        return x < z ? x : z;
    else
        return y < z ? y : z;
}
```

This could be rewritten as:

```
size_t min(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    return x < y ? min(x,z) : min(y,z);
}
```

Drop `inline` since the compiler knows better than you when to inline functions. `std::min` makes it clearer that you're using the standard library, but since you wrote `using namespace std;`, I didn't include it. You can further improve it by using a template:

```
template<class T> T min(T a, T b, T c) {
    return a < b ? std::min(a, c) : std::min(b, c);
}
```

It now works on all types supporting `operator<`.

**size_t**

I think `int` is more idiomatic than `size_t` for your M matrix, since you're not storing a size but a distance.

**Performance**: You could improve memory usage by storing only two rows of M. But this would prevent your from backtracking to print the alignment, and isn't a huge win anyway (except if you're working on very large strings).

**General comments** Your code is really straightforward and well-written. The algorithm is simply translated, and the rest of the function is simply the initialization: there's nothing complicated, and the code is easy to read. Good job!

Comment: “isn’t a huge win” – actually it is, even on moderately-sized strings (couple thousand characters each, which is just a short text). On still larger data a linear-space implementation becomes crucial. And note that, using Hirshberg’s algorithm, you can even retrieve the alignment in linear space.